# JavaScript unwanted event auto-triggered

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, dom-events

The on click event in the 70 line (`ob.addEventListener("click",onCl1(idTable[0],idTable));`) is being triggered without a reason. I have tried some other ways and it still reacts the same. I present the whole code as I think that it will be easier to find this bug:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var table1 = ["1","2","1","2"];
  var rightMoves = 0;
  var wrongMoves = 0;

        function shuffle(array) {
            var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
            while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
             currentIndex -= 1;
             temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
            }
            return array;
        }

        
        function printButtons(table1){
            shuffle(table1);
            var buttons = 0;
            var y,t,k,flag;
            var mybr = document.createElement('br');
      var idTable =["0","0","0","0"];
      var idT = 0;
            document.body.appendChild(mybr);
            for(var i =0 ; i<4; i++){
                 y = document.createElement("button");
                   t = document.createTextNode(table1[i]);
         for(var q =0; q<idT; q++){  // check if there is already a node with this id
            if(table1[i]==idTable[q]){
              k= table1[i]+"1";
              y.setAttribute("id",k);
              flag="true";
            }
            else{
              flag="false"; 
            }                 
         }
         if(flag =="false"){
            y.setAttribute("id",table1[i]);                
         }
         idTable[idT]=table1[i];
         idT=idT + 1;
                   y.appendChild(t);
                   document.body.appendChild(y);
         
                   buttons=buttons+1;
                    
        if (buttons == 2) {
            buttons = 0;
            document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        }

            }

       //menei na kalesw thn oncl1 gia to ka8e idtable 
         var ob = document.getElementById(idTable[0]); 
         var ob1 = document.getElementById(idTable[1]); 
         var ob2 = document.getElementById(idTable[2]); 
         var ob3 = document.getElementById(idTable[3]); 

         /*ob.onclick(onCl1(idTable[0],idTable));
         ob1.onclick(onCl1(idTable[1],idTable));
         ob2.onclick(onCl1(idTable[2],idTable));
         ob3.onclick(onCl1(idTable[3],idTable)); */
         
         //The problem is here
         ob.addEventListener("click",onCl1(idTable[0],idTable));


         
    }

      function onCl1(id1,idTable){
        var obj1 = document.getElementById(id1);
        obj1.disabled=true;
        var obj2,v,obj3,obj4;
        v=0;
        var temp = ["0","0","0"];
        for(var i =0 ; i<4 ; i++){
          if( id1 != idTable[i]){
            temp[v] = idTable[i];
            v=v+1;
          }
        }
        obj2=document.getElementById(temp[0]);
        obj2.onclick(onCl2(id1,temp[0]));
        obj3=document.getElementById(temp[1]);
        obj3.onclick(onCl2(id1,temp[1]));
        obj4=document.getElementById(temp[2]);
        obj4.onclick(onCl2(id1,temp[2]));

      }
      
      function onCl2(id1,id2){
          alert("fail");

      }
    
</script>
  <div id="div1">
    <button type="button" onclick="printButtons(table1)">play</button>
    <br>
  </div>

 
        

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling your event handler function instead of passing a function when you try to add the event listener.

```
     ob.addEventListener("click", function() { onCl1(idTable[0],idTable); });
```

Anytime you write `functionName( argument, argument, ... )` the function will be called at that point in the code. That's whats going on in your code; there are no magic rules for calls to `addEventListener()`.  Thus you have to wrap your function call with your parameters in another function, and pass that function as the second argument.

Comment: thanks! I think it is working with 
function() { onCl1(idTable[0],idTable); }  
What if I want to use obj.onclick ? Should I have to do the same with function () or there is another way ?

Comment: @user3498504 well you're better off with `.addEventListener()` anyway, but yes - the value of an "onclick" attribute must be a function.